# Advance after auto insterted tag - Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to auto advanced past the closing tag visual studio auto inserted?  For instance if I write `<div>`, visual studio will add `</div>`.  Is there a way where I can press a set of keys and advance over it?

Answer (score 0):

Pressing `End` will skip to the end of the line, which works well if the div is the only tag in the line. Otherwise you can press `Ctrl+Right` 3 times.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted but I guess it is the only one... :(.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the only answer. I wanna know if there's a single shortcut for it.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one nerdy enough to want to save 1 key stroke.